# Calling a materialized view from another materialized view in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

Is it possible to create a view, called *first_view* and in another view called *second_view* the first one is called? [This is the original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJHmv.png).

This is the first view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW first_view
AS SELECT atable.variable_one, btable.another_variable, ctable.variable_x
FROM a atable, b btable, c ctable
```

So that f(a,b,c) view can be called in f(ALL) which is f(a,b,c) including f(m) with aggregate functions.

Comment: Yes a MVIEW can select from another MVIEW. What exactly is your problem? What is the error you get? How does the second MVIEW look like? And why aren't you not joining your tables properly?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this was an exam question. Its theoretical so in theory, how would the joining work? These are all fictional

Comment: *In theory*, queries, views, tables, and materialised views are all relations, and should be interchangeable for DML SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is so simply that I assume that I do not understand your question properly:

Just use the first MVIEW the same way you use any other table or view in the second MVIEW:

```
create materialized view first_view
as
select a.column_one, b.column_two, c.column_three
from table_a a 
   join table_b b on a.id = b.aid
   join table_c c on b.id = c.bid;

create materialized view second_view
as
select x.some_column, f.*
from other_table x
   join first_view f on x.id = f.column_one;
```

Comment: Oh now I understand. Thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name